# Is there a way to use facets with the pg_search gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

I'd like to use facets in plus of standard search. Is there a way to make search results be itself "searched" with facets using pg_search?

As far as I can tell, pg_search_scope are mutually exclusive (is there a workaround?).
Thanks!

Example:

1) search blogs with word "test"

2) click link to get only articles from previous result that were also posted in june

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the original author and maintainer of `pg_search`.

A `pg_search_scope` works like any other Active Record scope, so you can chain them.

So let's say you have a model `Blog` with a `pg_search_scope` named `search_title` and another scope named `in_month` that takes two parameters, a month number and a year number. Something like this:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_title, :against => :title
  scope :in_month, lambda { |month_number, year_number| 
    where(:month => month_number, :year => year_number)
  }
end
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Blog.search_title("broccoli").in_month(6, 2011)
```

The reverse should also work:

```
Blog.in_month(6, 2011).search_title("broccoli")
```

And pagination solutions like Kaminari could also be called on the end.